# Is there a point to hogtying people, instead of shooting them?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

In Red Dead Redemption, you can lasso people and then hogtie them to take them captive. Sometimes, it's an option given by the mission. But if it's an option that not explicitly given to you by whatever mission you're doing, is there any point in doing so?

I've tried it a couple of times with people that have attacked me, but haven't really found anything to do with the tied people afterwards.

Comment: You ask that like you need a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once hogtied, try to put them on the railways tracks... :)
Try to do it with a lady to earn the Dastardly trophy.

Otherwise, you can give an hogtied man as a snack to a bear, a wolf pack or any other nature representant.
Remember, it's far west and no one told you you have to be brave and honest! ;)

Answer (score 8):

Certain bounty missions pay higher if the target is alive, so hogtying is useful there.

Also, it's just plain fun.